# Android/Firebase - Check to see if you are subscribed to topic

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am wondering if there is a way to test to see if you are subscribed to a topic on the android side of things.

Basically, I am *HOPING* that all devices will subscribe to a topic during their installation, when the token is first obtained by the device. However, there is always a chance that the device fails to subscribe. The FCM registration token should be installed on the device for a long time, and thus, the onTokenRefresh() method shouldn't be called again without clearing data, uninstall/reinstall, etc.

My idea was to test to see if the device is subscribed to a topic in my MainActivity, and if not, then try to subscribe again. If it fails to subscribe, then get a new token and try again, etc.

```
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // Subscribe to a topic
    Log.e(TAG, "Subscribing to topic");
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
```

So, I can subscribe and unsubscribe, but how do I check if the device is subscribed to a topic? I did my fair share of googling, and couldn't find anything, unfortunately.

I would greatly appreciate any/all assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is currently no way to check on the client side if they are subscribed to a topic.

The behavior for `subscribeToTopic` is it would immediately subscribe to the specified topic, if it fails, it would retry on it's own (unless your app was killed). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40109977/4625829).

I think that forcing the `onTokenRefresh` call just to make sure that `subscribeToTopic` is too much. You could simply just call it in your initial activity if you want, that way, everytime the app starts, it sends the subscription request.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this can be done by using this api: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances

As IID_TOKEN you need the FCM token and in the header you have to pass `Authentication`: `key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY`. You can find the server key as described here: [Firebase messaging, where to get Server Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427709/firebase-messaging-where-to-get-server-key).

Don't forget to include `details=true` as query parameter in the url, otherwise the topics won't be included in the response.

I would recommend writing a Cloud Function to encapsulate it, so you don't deploy your server key to the client.