# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging provide a Graphical User Interface to see, manage and monitor device topic subscriptions?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I am already obtaining successfully the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) device token by using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`. I used the following code to subscribe the client app to a topic:

```
String topic = "toronto";                                 
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic);
```

I assume everything is correct but in order to confirm, I would like to have a Graphical User Interface (GUI) provided by FCM to manage, monitor and see all of the devices that are subscribed to specific topics. With the code I used, I would expect to see the topic "toronto", and at least one device subscribed to that topic, for example by showing the FCM device token.

I was reading at https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances how it is possible to get information about app instances to find out details about a client app instance's subscriptions, including each topic name and subscribe date, but does FCM provide a GUI to see that?

UPDATE 1:

I was able to subscribe devices to topics and unsubscribe devices from topics. But when I want to confirm/monitor that a device was subscribed successfully, I am using this for example (for privacy I changed values of keys and tokens):

```
C:\curl>curl -X GET -k --header "Authorization: key=[My key]" "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/[My device token]?details=true"
{"applicationVersion":"22","connectDate":"2017-12-05","attestStatus":"NOT_ROOTED","application":"com.[My app]","scope":"*","authorizedEntity":"[My app ID]","rel":{"topics":{"San-salvador":{"addDate":"2017-12-05"}}},"connectionType":"WIFI","appSigner":"[My signature]","platform":"ANDROID"}
C:\curl>
```

I was expecting Firebase Cloud Messaging to provide a Graphical User Interface with a dashboard, charts and reports to see the topics that have been created and the list and number of devices subscribed to each of the topics, something similar to the Google Analytics reports, maybe even with maps to see where devices are subscribing from or anything visual that can help to visualize and monitor topic subscriptions. Instead, I am having to do everything with cURL with code similar to what I am showing in this UPDATE 1. I am surprised Firebase Cloud Messaging does not provide a GUI, since the tool comes from Google and they could easily provide a dashboard or something similar to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCM currently doesn't have a GUI that displays the list/count of topics you have or the subscribers (count/registration tokens) the topic has.

At most, you could use the [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances) (the one from your post) to check a single registration token to which topics it is subscribed to. However, do note that the Instance ID API was meant to be used on your Server side.

Other than that, you will have to implement your own mapping with the topics (which tokens are subscribed to it).

Kinda similar/possibly helpful posts:

- [Firebase Cloud Messaging - Check existing or available Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39632704/4625829)
- [Count subscribers of a topic in Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40861417/4625829)
- [Android/Firebase - Check to see if you are subscribed to topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46136752/4625829)
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging - Managing Registration Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42248240/4625829)