# Publishing/subscribing to FCM topics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've never used FCM (or GCM) before, but I'm looking into writing an app that will involve publishing messages to multiple devices, and "topics" seem to be a good approach.

From what I've read of the docs so far, my app server will publish messages to a named topic, so presumably it doesn't need to know about registration tokens for the recipient devices?

I believe a registration token must be specified when subscribing to a topic, so I guess a recipient device must still request a token before it can subscribe. What happens when the token expires - does the app have to subscribe to the topic again, using the new token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *so presumably it doesn't need to know about registration tokens for the recipient devices?*

No. It doesn't. But I would strongly suggest for you to save the registration tokens so you can keep track of them using the [Diagnostics tool](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en)  in the future.

> *What happens when the token expires - does the app have to subscribe to the topic again, using the new token?*

In Android, you simply have to call

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(<topic_name_here>);
```

to subscribe the device to a topic. The way on how I understand this works is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40133827/4625829), where the FirebaseMessaging class calls an instance of the FirebaseInstanceId and (presumably) subscribe the currently active registration token.

According to [@DiegoGiorgini's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43554044/4625829), the topic subscriptions are maintained if the token is *refreshed*.

<s>AFAIK (haven't encountered it yet), the corresponding registration token should be re-subscribed. Depending on where you implement the subscription.</s>

I would suggest having it on start of the app itself. Better if you'd have a list of topics (should there be more than one) on your App Server, and perhaps make use of the [InstanceID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server) to do the re-subscription if needed.

Comment: Many thanks. So the device doesn't need to explicitly pass its token in the call to subscribe? (I thought it did, but perhaps that was GCM, not FCM).

Comment: @AndrewStephens Nope. Just call the `subscribeToTopic()` from the client-side and it'll use the corresponding token. Cheers!