# Topic messaging android firebase dosent work

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried using

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

but it's been 1 day and half since i used this code line and still nothing shows up.
any suggustions?

I have read this but nothing helped:
[Android: Subscribe to Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055051/android-subscribe-to-firebase-cloud-messagingfcm-topic)

edit: my problem is that the topic i created doesnt show in my firebase notification console.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do provide more details.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Have you tried using a different topic name other than "news"?

Comment: yes, i tried football

Answer (score 1):

I've used topic based FCM in an app before and I actually had to send a message to the topic to which I was subscribing to get it to show up in the Firebase Cloud Messaging console. You could use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) or a chrome plugin such as [ARC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to send a message on that topic.

Comment: can i get an explanation on how to send a message from ARC? ive all ready installed it.

Comment: you need to POST to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` you have to set your Authorization header to your authorization key. Set the Content-Type to application/json. The payload is just JSON. Take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#http_post_request) for more info

Comment: im getting this error while using the ARC: "JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
"