# Firebase Cloud Messaging Send vs Received

Tags: firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

we are using firebase cloud messaging for sending notification for the user.  when we going though the cloud messaging report we fount that only 5% of total send message is getting received.

[image]

why is it so? and how can we make sure that maximum messages getting received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283587/firebase-cloud-messaging-reports-wrong).

I found this discussion in the comments to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055267/2813152). Turns out that subscribing to a topic in FCM is not necessarily permanent. So don't subscribe users to a topic once. Instead do it on every app start, although it is

> "not technically necessary. It may depend on your use case. For
> example, if you want a global topic where all users are a member of,
> you'd have to make sure that they are subscribed to it. Putting the
> subscribe method when the app starts guarantees this."

- -@AL.

In my Case this fixed it for me. Now the Notifications are received by a lot more people than before. Only the open-count is still not working for me. It is always on zero.